# understand apache error log (maybe an attack?)

Tags: log-files

anyome can help to understand the apache error log?
my website has benn recently attacked (iframe at bottom page).

my website in ona dedicated server with centos ad directadmin
than you all.

```
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9baa0e000-7fc9bac0e000 ---p 00015000 08:01 123164                     /lib64/libselinux.so.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bac0e000-7fc9bac10000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 123164                     /lib64/libselinux.so.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bac10000-7fc9bac11000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bac11000-7fc9bac19000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 370692                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bac19000-7fc9bae18000 ---p 00008000 08:01 370692                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bae18000-7fc9bae19000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 370692                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bae19000-7fc9bae3d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 370449                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bae3d000-7fc9bb03c000 ---p 00024000 08:01 370449                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb03c000-7fc9bb03e000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 370449                     /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb03e000-7fc9bb040000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123097                     /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb040000-7fc9bb23f000 ---p 00002000 08:01 123097                     /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb23f000-7fc9bb240000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 123097                     /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb240000-7fc9bb2d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 370469                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb2d2000-7fc9bb4d1000 ---p 00092000 08:01 370469                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb4d1000-7fc9bb4d5000 rw-p 00091000 08:01 370469                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb4d5000-7fc9bb501000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 370409                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb501000-7fc9bb701000 ---p 0002c000 08:01 370409                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb701000-7fc9bb703000 rw-p 0002c000 08:01 370409                     /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb703000-7fc9bb851000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123083                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bb851000-7fc9bba51000 ---p 0014e000 08:01 123083                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bba51000-7fc9bba55000 r--p 0014e000 08:01 123083                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bba55000-7fc9bba56000 rw-p 00152000 08:01 123083                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bba56000-7fc9bba5b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bba5b000-7fc9bbb53000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418539                     /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbb53000-7fc9bbd53000 ---p 000f8000 08:01 418539                     /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbd53000-7fc9bbd55000 rw-p 000f8000 08:01 418539                     /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbd55000-7fc9bbd57000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123106                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbd57000-7fc9bbf57000 ---p 00002000 08:01 123106                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbf57000-7fc9bbf58000 r--p 00002000 08:01 123106                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbf58000-7fc9bbf59000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 123106                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bbf59000-7fc9bc091000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418563                     /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc091000-7fc9bc290000 ---p 00138000 08:01 418563                     /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc290000-7fc9bc29a000 rw-p 00137000 08:01 418563                     /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc29a000-7fc9bc29b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc29b000-7fc9bc2b1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123130                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc2b1000-7fc9bc4b0000 ---p 00016000 08:01 123130                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc4b0000-7fc9bc4b1000 r--p 00015000 08:01 123130                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc4b1000-7fc9bc4b2000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 123130                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc4b2000-7fc9bc4b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc4b6000-7fc9bc507000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418573                     /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc507000-7fc9bc706000 ---p 00051000 08:01 418573                     /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc706000-7fc9bc709000 rw-p 00050000 08:01 418573                     /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc709000-7fc9bc71e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123126                     /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc71e000-7fc9bc91d000 ---p 00015000 08:01 123126                     /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc91d000-7fc9bc91e000 r--p 00014000 08:01 123126                     /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc91e000-7fc9bc91f000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 123126                     /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc91f000-7fc9bc921000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc921000-7fc9bc9a3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123109                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bc9a3000-7fc9bcba2000 ---p 00082000 08:01 123109                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcba2000-7fc9bcba3000 r--p 00081000 08:01 123109                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcba3000-7fc9bcba4000 rw-p 00082000 08:01 123109                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcba4000-7fc9bcbb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123155                     /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcbb5000-7fc9bcdb5000 ---p 00011000 08:01 123155                     /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcdb5000-7fc9bcdb6000 r--p 00011000 08:01 123155                     /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcdb6000-7fc9bcdb7000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 123155                     /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcdb7000-7fc9bcdb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcdb9000-7fc9bcdf4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418574                     /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcdf4000-7fc9bcff3000 ---p 0003b000 08:01 418574                     /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcff3000-7fc9bcff4000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 418574                     /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bcff4000-7fc9bd121000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123193                     /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd121000-7fc9bd320000 ---p 0012d000 08:01 123193                     /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd320000-7fc9bd341000 rw-p 0012c000 08:01 123193                     /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd341000-7fc9bd345000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd345000-7fc9bd38b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123195                     /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd38b000-7fc9bd58b000 ---p 00046000 08:01 123195                     /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd58b000-7fc9bd591000 rw-p 00046000 08:01 123195                     /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd591000-7fc9bd5cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418257                     /usr/local/lib/libpng.so.3.1.2.44
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd5cc000-7fc9bd7cc000 ---p 0003b000 08:01 418257                     /usr/local/lib/libpng.so.3.1.2.44
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd7cc000-7fc9bd7cd000 rw-p 0003b000 08:01 418257                     /usr/local/lib/libpng.so.3.1.2.44
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd7cd000-7fc9bd84b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418553                     /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bd84b000-7fc9bda4a000 ---p 0007e000 08:01 418553                     /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bda4a000-7fc9bda50000 rw-p 0007d000 08:01 418553                     /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6.6.2
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bda50000-7fc9bda78000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 417818                     /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bda78000-7fc9bdc78000 ---p 00028000 08:01 417818                     /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdc78000-7fc9bdc7b000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 417818                     /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdc7b000-7fc9bdc81000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdc81000-7fc9bdcad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 417819                     /usr/local/lib/libmhash.so.2.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdcad000-7fc9bdeac000 ---p 0002c000 08:01 417819                     /usr/local/lib/libmhash.so.2.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdeac000-7fc9bdead000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 417819                     /usr/local/lib/libmhash.so.2.0.1
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdead000-7fc9bdeb4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123157                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9bdeb4000-7fc9be0b4000 ---p 00007000 08:01 123157                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be0b4000-7fc9be0b5000 r--p 00007000 08:01 123157                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be0b5000-7fc9be0b6000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 123157                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be0b6000-7fc9be0cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 418533                     /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be0cc000-7fc9be2cb000 ---p 00016000 08:01 418533                     /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be2cb000-7fc9be2cc000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 418533                     /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be2cc000-7fc9be2d5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123093                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be2d5000-7fc9be4d4000 ---p 00009000 08:01 123093                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be4d4000-7fc9be4d5000 r--p 00008000 08:01 123093                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be4d5000-7fc9be4d6000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 123093                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be4d6000-7fc9be504000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be504000-7fc9be520000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 123047                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be688000-7fc9be716000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be71e000-7fc9be720000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be720000-7fc9be721000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 123047                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fc9be721000-7fc9be722000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 123047                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fff505bf000-7fff505e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] 7fff505ff000-7fff50600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[Tue Jan 31 01:08:11 2012] [error] [client 157.55.16.230] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

Comment: that ip seem be bing bot: (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The IP address belongs to one of Bing's crawlers, so it appears that what's happening is that Apache is throwing an error while the search engine scans your site. This could be a number of different things, but the most likely is that your server is misconfigured or your robots.txt file is bad.

Answer (score 1):

looks to me someone is trying to exploit php by trying to overflow a chunk of memory.. That is like a coredump inside a error log